# Jumbotron and Footer creating white border eventhough I have put a background color of black

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am developing my first website and I am trying to use a large image as the front of the home screen. When implementing jumbotron, it creates a white border around the image even though I keep setting my background color to black. Same thing with my footer and when I put a background color, it only sets the color to area region of the footer and not the whole bottom of the screen. How exactly can I fix this because I am trying to make the bottom of the screen black and also I would like to make the border around the picture blue. Below are two photos of what the home screen looks like so that you can see where the white borders are. Thank you for the help.

[This is the footer of my website. I don't understand why only a small portion of the footer is black and not the whole bottom.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VO7b.jpg)

[This is the large image that I have put on my screen. In my css I have used it as a background image. Every time I change the background color to black the border around the image stays as white.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aff3r.jpg)

The first tag above container is "div class="jumbotron". The code snippet is not allowing me to put this in for some reason.

```
  <div class="container">`
    <div class="row text-center">`
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"role="button">Hello</a>`
   `</div>`
  </div>`
</div>`

<!-- Write your comments here -->

<footer class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <p class="col-sm-4">
      &copy; Stock
    </p>
    <ul class="col-sm-8">
        <li class="col-sm-1"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/twitter.svg"></li>
        <li class="col-sm-1"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/facebook.svg"></li>
        <li class="col-sm-1"> <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/instagram.svg"></li>
        <li class="col-sm-1"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/medium.svg"></li>
    </ul>
    <p class="col-sm-3">About Us</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
.jumbotron {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-image:url('https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs194-26/fa14/upload/files/proj3/cs194-di/proj3_sutardja_anthony/imgs/earth_road_joined/road.png');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 700px;
  margin:75px;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  border-style:solid;
  background-color:black;

}

footer {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  color:red;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  margin:10;
  background-color:black;
}

footer .col-sm-8 {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;
}

footer ul {
  list-style: none;
}

footer li img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

Comment: You mean the Stackoverflow editor won't let you put the jumbotron in there?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the white is coming from the page background, because you are using margins which do not extend the background of an element.

Try adding `body { background-color: black}` to your css

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working **plunker** for you:

> https://plnkr.co/edit/h5X9Q1rIwFuMsY3N1YGD?p=preview

Added

```
body{
  background-color:black;
}
```

Now I hope it is as you wanted it. Have fun playing and developing your first site. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You apply black background to the container.
The rule of thumb in such situations is use another div to wrap your container.

You may want to do something like this

```
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <p class="col-sm-4">
      &copy; Stock
    </p>
    <ul class="col-sm-8">
      ...
    </ul>
    <p class="col-sm-3">About Us</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Also, I would recommend you to do the same for the inline elements for better readability of the code.

Consider changing

```
    <p class="col-sm-4">
      &copy; Stock
    </p>
```

to

```
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p>&copy; Stock</p>
    </div>
```

For the image issue, please show the code.
It seems to be you need to reset margin and padding

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```